# Always shows different name on log before launching

Tags: android

when i launch my project named"math table" is show Project dependency found:......
why??
any help will be thankfull

```
[2014-05-02 11:53:13 - MathTable] Android Launch!
[2014-05-02 11:53:13 - MathTable] adb is running normally.
[2014-05-02 11:53:13 - MathTable] Performing com.example.mathtable.MenuActivity activity launch
[2014-05-02 11:53:13 - MathTable] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2014-05-02 11:53:15 - MathTable] Uploading MathTable.apk onto device 'DellVenue7000110236'
[2014-05-02 11:53:16 - MathTable] Installing MathTable.apk...
[2014-05-02 11:53:25 - MathTable] Success!
[2014-05-02 11:53:25 - MathTable] Project dependency found, installing: AnimalsAndBirds
[2014-05-02 11:53:25 - AnimalsAndBirds] Uploading AnimalsAndBirds.apk onto device 'DellVenue7000110236'
[2014-05-02 11:53:27 - AnimalsAndBirds] Installing AnimalsAndBirds.apk...
[2014-05-02 11:53:34 - AnimalsAndBirds] Success!
[2014-05-02 11:53:34 - MathTable] Starting activity com.example.mathtable.MenuActivity on device DellVenue7000110236
[2014-05-02 11:53:34 - MathTable] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.mathtable/.MenuActivity }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think its very basic stuff......but any ways..

first go to your project properties...
then select android their and then check  whether their is any other project source is used by your project or not..is their is then remove it if u dont need it